# /usr/include missing from NDK (r16b)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I've just installed NDK (r16b) using the SDK manager, but is `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-x86/usr/include` (I'm on OS X) supposed to exist? I can't seem to find it. I have `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-x86/usr/lib`. The following is the result from running `tree` at `/arch-x86`:

```
arch-x86 tree
.
└── usr
    └── lib
        ├── crtbegin_dynamic.o
        ├── crtbegin_so.o
        ├── crtbegin_static.o
        ├── crtend_android.o
        ├── crtend_so.o
        ├── libEGL.so
        ├── libGLESv1_CM.so
        ├── libGLESv2.so
        ├── libGLESv3.so
        ├── libOpenMAXAL.so
        ├── libOpenSLES.so
        ├── libandroid.so
        ├── libc.a
        ├── libc.so
        ├── libcamera2ndk.so
        ├── libdl.so
        ├── libjnigraphics.so
        ├── liblog.so
        ├── libm.a
        ├── libm.so
        ├── libmediandk.so
        ├── libstdc++.a
        ├── libstdc++.so
        ├── libvulkan.so
        ├── libz.a
        └── libz.so

2 directories, 26 files
```

Is there a way to generate the `include` directory? I'm actually looking for the file `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-x86/usr/include/android/api-level.h`

Comment: you should read about the [unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-release-r16/docs/UnifiedHeadersMigration.md)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest SDK, `api-level.h` is located at

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/android/api-level.h
```

In the future, if you can not find one file due to the directory hierarchy changed, you can do like following to find out

```
$ cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
$ find . -name "api-level.h"
```